# Tab content doesn't fix under nav tabs

Tags: html, css, tabs

Maybe it is a simple situation, but for me, I can’t fix it. So I am making a page using bootstrap after a picture model. I have to make a navigation pannel, but the tab content it doesn’t start under the tabs, it is over them. Here is some code:

```
<div id="content">
     <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right stil" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Enterprise Edition</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab"  href="#">SMB Edition</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="my-tab-content">
        <div id="smbedition" class="tab-pane active">
            <img src="imgs/header.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After this, it's looking like this, as you can see, the white part in line with the 2 tabs is the content. Can you please help me?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with `the tab content it doesn't start under the tabs, it is over them`? Over them like in z-index over them, or vertically aligned above them? Also: I can't reproduce your problem with the code you pasted in OP (take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24539/ ) Sure it's not the CSS or any other HTML making your problem? AND One last thing: This question has NOTHING to do with `bootstrap-modal` ! ;)

Comment: One last thing: your heading on OP says "fix", if you're positioning any element please add the suited CSS. Else it will be impossible to help you out! ;)

Comment: I've found the problem: i've added the class navbar-right so the tabs to be oriented to the right. Now it ok with tab content, but I can't change the orientation of the tabs :( They are on the left side of the page and I want them to the right.

Comment: You need to clearify that a bit. You managed to put the content below the navigation, but it's not horizontally aligned right? Please show more of your HTML structure so we can see what classes you've used on your `<nav></nav>` element ...